# Darknet and Data Augmentation

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision, yolo

In the darknet deep learning framework `.cfg` files we see parameters like

```
angle, saturation, exposure
```

These parameters are used for data augmentation in classic image classification problems.
Does Darknet automatically perform image augmentation automatically for object detection by setting up these parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Random augmentation is performed automatically by darknet. No need to perform data augmentation. For reference refer to the following link:
https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/wiki/CFG-Parameters-in-the-%5Bnet%5D-section